# Can Compodoc generate markdown documentation, as opposed to its default HTML documentation?

Tags: angular, documentation, compodoc

After a bunch if digging, I still can't figure out if Compodoc can generate markdown documentation from typescript comments. The Visual Studio Team Services Wiki feature only supports markdown files. If it does support generating markdown documentation, what is the CLI option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is NO, not at this time. I've posted a feature request to Azure DevOps to support HTML/CSS/Javascript files for Wiki documentation. Others have done the same. It's a popular request.